# Flutter Syncing LocalDB With RemoteDB

Tags: mysql, flutter, sqlite, android-syncadapter

I have data stored locally in sqlite.  I have a remote MySql server.  In android I could setup SyncAdapter to handle the syncing between the localdb and the remotedb.

When a record is saved locally and there is an internet connection it should push the data to the server in the background.  It should also periodically update the data stored in SqLite.

Now I'm trying to find the equivalent of SyncAdapter in flutter to do this but I can't seem to find one.  How would I implement this functionality in flutter **without** having to use firebase?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Nope.  Implementing my own solution using Sqlite and Background Services.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I went after Firebase. Did a lot of research without any success in this one. did u find any solutions yet?

Comment: I think this question falls under `help/don't ask` [help/dont-ask]

Comment: You can use ObjectBox to store the data and sync it. Have a look at this https://youtu.be/AxYbdriXKI8

Answer (score 1):

You can use [realm-db](https://realm.io/) for it. You can't sync local-db to remote easily. But everything is so easy with realm-db

Answer (score 0):

for this work, you need to add one boolean column in your database which checks if data send to the web or not. then use WorkManager to check periodically if data is updated to host or not. for this work, you can use [Flutter Work manager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager).